# vbs file to save the current dictionary in txt file

Tags: directory, save

i want batch file to save the current dictionary in txt file 
for example

```
     currentDirectory = left(WScript.ScriptFullName,(Len(WScript.ScriptFullName))-      (len(WScript.ScriptName)))
     WScript.Echo currentDirectory
     currentdirectory > currentDirectory.txt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a batch file, there is no need to use wscript. Just a `cd` is enough:

```
cd > c:\currentDir.txt
```

And using `cscript` and `VBS`:

```
currentDirectory = left(WScript.ScriptFullName,(Len(WScript.ScriptFullName))-      (len(WScript.ScriptName)))
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile("currentDirectory.txt")
objFile.WriteLine (currentDirectory)
objFile.Close
```

Comment: can u update the answer to do file with the current directory ??